# JqueryMobile - Listviews right arrow

Tags: jquery

Is possible to make a standard jquerymobile listview without the right arrow image that apears on the rigt of the li object?

[Standard list view](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/#docs/lists/lists-ul.html)

Thanks

Answer (score 52):

In versions of jQuery Mobile >= 1.0, use the [`data-icon` attribute](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html):

```
<li data-icon="false"><a href="#yourref">Your Text</a></li>
```

`data-icon="false"` attribute removes the arrow.

Comment: Works for me, jquery mobile alpha 4.

Comment: should have marked it as the answer, just tried it and it worked. kudos

Answer (score 10):

Another way of doing this will be by adding data-icon="false" to the **ul** instead of **li** as indicated by Jacob above.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-icon="false">
```

This way, all child objects within the listview will by default carry no icons.

Answer (score 0):

If icon still persist just remove a tag or wrap it with a div.
e.g

```
<div>
  <a> //your stuff here </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `data-icon-"false"` on the `li` tag

Comment: Why down vote? This does work. small type, should be `data-icon="false"`