# Jquery Mobile 1.0a2 remove listview arrow

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I was trying to remove the right arrow which comes in listview by default. Searched for a while came across `data-icon="false"`but it did not work. Then i searched more and found this post [JqueryMobile - Listviews right arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580875/jquerymobile-listviews-right-arrow) (I may be duplicating this post, please excuse me for that)

My question is, how exactly can i remove the arrow in 1.0a2? Apparently this can be done using DOM surgery, can anyone elaborate this?

Comment: Why are you still using 1.0a2 when the 1.2 has just been released?

Comment: I think you add data-icon="false" in ul and this not work. try it in every li. I tested this in 1.0 and this work perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround would be to "manually" remove the arrows with the following JS / jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    $('li').removeClass("ui-btn-icon-right"); 
});
```

Here's a full working example, have a try:

```
<!DOCTYPE unspecified PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile.structure-1.0a2.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('li').removeClass("ui-btn-icon-right"); 
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="p1">
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a" >                   
                <li><a href="#p2">Go to page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#p3">Go to page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="p2">
        Hello! This is page 2!!!
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="p3">
        Hello! This is page 3!!!
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

However, I suggest to get the latest version of jQuery Mobile (1.2 at the moment), which corrected several bugs and which is in this way more stable.

Check the website for more information: http://jquerymobile.com/

Hope this helps.

Comment: this not a good idea to use a function jquery, when you have a parameter like : data-icon="false". (your function will delete a class or we can from first disable the creation of this class)

Answer (score 1):

for newer jQuery Mobile versions, just set `data-icon="false"`, see also the [documentation](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.4/listview/)

> To prevent icons from appearing altogether, set the data-icon
>   attribute to "false".

[image]